# How to create a hierarchical folder from an integer in PHP?

Tags: php, string, substring

I need to create subfolders for a large image archive. I currently use this approach

```
$image_id = 1234567;
$id = sprintf('%08d', $image_id);
$a = substr($id,0,2);
$b = substr($id,2,2);
$c = substr($id,4,2);
$folder = "$a/$b/$c";
$file = "$folder/$image_id.jpg";
```

Since this process should be conducted every time to find the image location, I wonder if there is an easier or more efficient approach to do so.

I am not stuck to this folder structure, and just need to distribute the files over subfolders to improve the filersystem performance.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to preserve the same folder structure, I'm not sure if this is more efficient, but it is a bit more elegant:

```
$image_id = 1234567;
$id = sprintf('%08d', $image_id);
$folder = implode('/', (str_split($id, 2)));
$file = "$folder/$image_id.jpg";
```

This shouldn't have a big drag on performance, but it is a bit slower than putting all the files in the same folder or storing the complete path to the file along with its id.

Comment: You're right, it's more elegant, though, I think creating an array and then `implode` in PHP might not be in favor of performance. However, I can change the folder structure.